# Cannot get rid of comma's in fizbuz

Tags: javascript

I am doing a simple fizzBuzz function.  The goal is to get fizz for 3 buzz for 5 and fizzBuzz for 15.  The added trick is to have each one on its own line.

```
function fizzbuzz(n) {

    var array = [];
    for(var i =1; i<=n; i++) {
      if(i % 15 ===0){
            array.push('FizzBuzz');
        }
      else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            array.push('Fizz');
        }
      else if(i % 5 === 0) {
            array.push('Buzz');
        }
      else {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
        return array + '\n'  ;
}
 console.log(fizzbuzz(15));
```

The code works.  The problem is that I am getting

```
console.log(1,2,fizz,4,buzz,5,etc)
```

I need to be getting each number on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

Just explicitly `.join()` your array:

```
console.log(fizzbuzz(15).join("\n"));
```

Passing the returned array to `console.log()` will implicitly turn the array into a string. The way that's done is effectively the same as calling `.join(",")`, so you get commas. Explicitly doing the `.join()` yourself lets you supply any separator you want.

*edit* — a smart person notes in a comment that you need to take away that `+ "\n"` in your `return` statement. That right there will trigger the default `.join()`. Alternatively, you could do your `.join("\n")` there.

Comment: It should be noted that for this example the `return` still needs to be changed to just return the array, so that the implicit string conversion won't take place.

Answer (score 2):

Use join:

```
[1,2,'fizz',4,'buzz',5].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simple "join" the array:

```
function fizzbuzz(n) {

    var array = [];
    for(var i =1; i<=n; i++) {
      if(i % 15 ===0){
            array.push('FizzBuzz');
        }
      else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            array.push('Fizz');
        }
      else if(i % 5 === 0) {
            array.push('Buzz');
        }
      else {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
        return array.join('\n');
}
 console.log(fizzbuzz(15));
```

Answer (score 0):

### The point of fizzbuzz is to demonstrate elementary coding skill

This exercise is testing that you can use a for loop, you understand elementary Boolean arithmetic and you can write a conditional. That's the purpose of this exercise.

If you really need everything on it's own line, just skip the array altogether and `console.log('Fizzbuzz')` instead. Alternately create a string and append to that, making sure to write a newline character each time round the loop. Alternately, you could compose your array and `join('\n')`.

I doubt you'd fail for not returning. That's not the spirit of fizzbuzz.

To be frank though, if you're finding this hard, perhaps you are one of those people that Fizzbuzz is designed to eliminate. Harsh, sorry, there are other career options open to you. This should be a trivial 30 second job.

Comment: I don't think the op struggled with fizz buzz. His real question was about string manipulation for his output.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being too harsh. It is a fairly trivial question though.

Comment: True. Being as trivial as it is, I'm sure this question has already been asked in some other form.

Comment: @Kaiged - I would probably expect someone trying for a job as a programmer to be able to basic string manipulation without resorting to SO. Coding isn't for everyone. Again, I'm probably being harsh.